# How to decode ysoserial .net payload

Tags: exploit, appsec, deserialization

Is there any way to decode ysoserial .net payload?

For instance
I'm creating payload with:

```
ysoserial.exe -f BinaryFormatter -o base64 -c "ping test.com" -g WindowsIdentity
```

Is there any convenient way to reverse the payload to understand which command was encoded.